# How to debug a windows driver with IDA and use its corresponding IDB?

Tags: windows, debugging, reverse-engineering, windbg, ida

I am familiar with using windbg or IDA for remote kernel debugging, but right now i have extracted a kernel driver from an executable, and have done static analysis on its IDB and renamed a lot of variables, what is the easiest way of using my IDB file to debug the driver on the remote debugee when it gets loaded by the executable?

I know how to attach to remote kernel using IDA, but how can i use my current IDB file, and put breakpoint on some of its functions so it they get hit when the driver is loaded? (I dont have the corresponding pdb file for the driver so i can't use symbols for breakpoint)

Comment: I also have this exact same question. The answer from blabb doesn't answer the OP's question at all.

Answer (score 3):

this is a vanilla windbg answer to break on any DriverInit

once you have Broken on DriverInit You Can Lookup and Set bp on all MajorFunctions

Assuming you have a regular kd Connection

use sxe -ibp;.reboot to reboot the target

on reconnection the target will break very Early as below

```
kd> sxe ibp;.reboot
Shutdown occurred at (Sun Oct 18 02:58:09.077 2020 )...unloading all symbol tables.
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to Windows 7 7601 x86 compatible target at (xxx), ptr64 FALSE
Kernel Debugger connection established.  (Initial Breakpoint requested)
```

once broken set a breakpoint on nt!IopLoadDriver

inside this function search for an indirect Call
that Calls the  _DRIVER_OBJECT->DriverInit

```
kd> ?? #FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_DRIVER_OBJECT , DriverInit)
long 0x2c
```

like

```
nt!IopLoadDriver+0x7ea:
829d5355 ff562c call dword ptr[esi+2Ch] ds:84f2928c={cdrom!FxDriverEntry (87eb53cf)}
```

set a break point here to

you are now set to enter almost every driver that is loaded
once you are on entrypoint of any Driver
use the DriverObject (an argument the DriverEntry Takes )
and Set Breakpoints on each MAJORFunction

```
kd> bp . "du poi(@esi+1c+4);gc"
kd> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  829d4b6a     0001 (0001) nt!IopLoadDriver
     1 e Disable Clear  829d5355     0001 (0001) nt!IopLoadDriver+0x7ea "du poi(@esi+1c+4);gc"

kd> bd 0
kd> bl
     0 d Enable Clear  829d4b6a     0001 (0001) nt!IopLoadDriver
     1 e Disable Clear  829d5355     0001 (0001) nt!IopLoadDriver+0x7ea "du poi(@esi+1c+4);gc"

kd> g
841bd1d0  "\Driver\Null.Ѕ捁印䍁䥐停偎〰〰"
84f18718  "\Driver\Beep.Б浍摌䂈蓶䈸蓶...."
84eef210  "\Driver\VgaSave"
84eb2860  "\Driver\RDPCDDᛛ..В浍慃憠褎.蓫菌蓲"
84e903c0  "\Driver\RDPENCDD..浍摌읨蓤潤獷獜獹整.尲牤癩牥"
84e90400  "屳摲数据摤献獹"
84ef15c0  "\Driver\RDPREFMP..牉..蓧"
84ef4a78  "\FileSystem\Msfs.В浍慃冀褘蝴蓳荤蓶"
84f191f0  "\FileSystem\Npfs.З獍䑆.°"
```